# why I could not install dlib

Tags: python, django, dlib

I was trying to install dlib but I couldn't install this.
Please help. I am getting error while installing dlib.
I am not able to install this, Please help me out to install this.
I did research on it but I couldn't get it. can anyone help me to solve this...

**Error:**

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [122 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      Building extension for Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azri193f\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azri193f\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azri193f\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -A x64'
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 10 2010
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      CMake Warning in C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/build/temp.win-amd64-3.9/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:
        The binary and/or source directory paths may be too long to generate Visual
        Studio 10 files for this project.  Consider choosing shorter directory
        names to build this project with Visual Studio 10.  A more detailed
        explanation follows.

        There is a bug in the VS 10 IDE that renders property dialog fields blank
        for files referenced by full path in the project file.  However, CMake must
        reference at least one file by full path:

          C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c

        This is because some Visual Studio tools would append the relative path to
        the end of the referencing directory path, as in:

          C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/build/temp.win-amd64-3.9/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/../../../../../../../../Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c

        and then incorrectly complain that the file does not exist because the path
        length is too long for some internal buffer or API.  To avoid this problem
        CMake must use a full path for this file which then triggers the VS 10
        property dialog bug.


      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      CMake Warning in C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/build/temp.win-amd64-3.9/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:
        The binary and/or source directory paths may be too long to generate Visual
        Studio 10 files for this project.  Consider choosing shorter directory
        names to build this project with Visual Studio 10.  A more detailed
        explanation follows.

        There is a bug in the VS 10 IDE that renders property dialog fields blank
        for files referenced by full path in the project file.  However, CMake must
        reference at least one file by full path:

          C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

        This is because some Visual Studio tools would append the relative path to
        the end of the referencing directory path, as in:

          C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/build/temp.win-amd64-3.9/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/../../../../../../../../Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

        and then incorrectly complain that the file does not exist because the path
        length is too long for some internal buffer or API.  To avoid this problem
        CMake must use a full path for this file which then triggers the VS 10
        property dialog bug.


      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe (found version "3.9.5")
      -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/libs/Python39.lib
      -- pybind11 v2.2.4
      -- Using CMake version: 3.22.4
      -- Compiling dlib version: 19.24.0
      CMake Error at C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/dlib/cmake_utils/set_compiler_specific_options.cmake:31 (message):
        C++11 is required to use dlib, but the version of Visual Studio you are
        using is too old and doesn't support C++11.  You need Visual Studio 2015 or
        newer.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/dlib/cmake_utils/test_for_sse4/CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)


      CMake Error at C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/dlib/cmake_utils/check_if_sse4_instructions_executable_on_host.cmake:13 (try_compile):
        Failed to configure test project build system.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/dlib/cmake_utils/set_compiler_specific_options.cmake:13 (include)
        C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/dlib/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-azri193f/dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d/build/temp.win-amd64-3.9/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azri193f\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
          setup(
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azri193f\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\setup.py", line 134, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-azri193f\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
        File "c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-azri193f\\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-azri193f\\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\manoj\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-azri193f\\dlib_4d5ab15ff10d4c9cb3ee98bad5a48c2d\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.2; however, version 22.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\manoj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Please help. I am getting error while installing dlib.
I am not able to install this, Please help me out to install this.
I did research on it but I couldn't get it. can anyone help me to solve this...

Comment: Have you tried doing `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')`?

Comment: No, i didn't try

Comment: well done, it worked